# using of delphi dll in java spring project

Tags: java, delphi, dll, java-native-interface

Please help me to put details together.
I've scanned internet for lot of hours but result is not good.

SO, I have:

1. Delphi written DLL for JNI (from 32 bit Delphi on 32 bit comp)
2. Java web project (Tomcat, Spring) on my 64 bit MAC
3. System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")) writes "/tmp" and it is right
4. in /tmp I have qvs.dll from delphi

When I start project I get exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no qvs in java.library.path
```

1. Java code to load library:

   System.loadLibrary("qvs")

I tried lot of combinations with the same result.
Only one reason I can't try. Can I use 32-bit DLL on my 64-bit MAC ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't use DLLs on a Mac at all, unless your Mac runs Windows.

Comment: I just tried to make the same steps on 32 bit MAC with 32 bit JRE. I 've got the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Windows DLL can not be used on a Mac OS system (except in a Windows virtual machine).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to make all of it on my WIN-server.

Answer (score 6):

It won't be possible to do as you wished, for two reasons:

- You can not run a Windows library (.dll file) on a Mac (.dylib);
- You can not launch a 32 bit library from a 64 bit process.

Therefore, I see three solutions:

- Make everything on the Windows side (how would use Mac for a server, anyway?);
- Use the Mac OS version of Delphi XE2 compiler (or the FPC compiler) to create a small server application in object pascal code (using sockets), then access to it from the 64 bit Java process, out-of-process. Not an easy task - [this library is not free, but may help you](http://www.remobjects.com/da/java.aspx);
- Or of course, rewrite the code in Java or its byte code: perhaps the [Oxygene for Java](http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/java.aspx) or the [FPC JVM back-end](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_JVM) may help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to make all of it on my WIN-server.

Comment: @mad That is the easiest solution!